# Using pick in array Nuxt 3 useFetch

Tags: vuejs3, server-side-rendering, nuxtjs3

I'm trying to replicate the nuxt 3 `useFetch` sample but no luck so far.
https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/data-fetching#usefetch

My post.vue page contains the below code:

```html
<template>
  <section>
    <div v-for="mountain in mountains" :key="mountain">{{mountain}}</div>
  </section>
</template>

<script setup>
  const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig()

  const { data: mountains, pending, error, refresh } = await useFetch('/mountains',{
    baseURL: runtimeConfig.public.apiBase,
    pick: ['title']
  })
  
  console.log(mountains.value)
</script>
```

For some reason the data is not shown in template.
The `console.log()` shows `Proxy {title: undefined}`

I've realized that removing the pick option solves the issue, so I'm wondering if `pick` only works for objects and can't be used in arrays.
It's odd because the sample is using an array https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/composables/use-fetch.

Comment: What happens if you try `{{ mountain.title }}`? Also, what do you see in the Vue devtools? Using the `pre` html tag can be useful on `mountains` too if you want to inspect it more easily.

Comment: Doing `{{ mountain.title }}` just returns a Nuxt error 500 because it's not defined. Apparently `pick` only works on objects and I had to use `transform` for parsing arrays. But I need some Nuxt guru to confirm. I guess that doing pick on array converts the array into a single object with an undefined title property

Comment: Didn't used that myself (yet). What about the 2nd part of my previous comment, did you tried the 2?

Comment: As you found out and as the documentation says, `pick` works on the result - not on all elements of an result array. That could be an improvement though.

Comment: Could probably be solved by making an iteration on the collection tho. I think I saw somebody achieving that quite easily!

Comment: Mainly thanks to `transform`.

Answer (score 1):

The pick option currently works only if you are fetching one document (one Js object).

In the official docs you can see they are fetching a specific document in their API: https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/data-fetching.

One option you have is to make an API route that returns one object only.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `<div>`, you are trying to return `{{mountain}}`, but at the time this page loads there is no such variable--because the const mountains hasn't been fetched yet. What you need to do is add a `<div v-if="mountains" v-for="mountain in mountains" :key="mountain">{{mountain}}</div>` 
For the brief moment it takes before the `useFetch` function to return mountains,the `<div>` will not try to show {{mountains}}, because the `v-if` prevents the `<div>` from being shown in the first place.

Comment: Don't mix `v-if` and `v-for`.